# Create a template for exam

Tags: templates, exam

I want to create a template for exams such as [this one](https://www.alloschool.com/element/127185) and in first step, I want to create this page header : [image]
Any help is welcome.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Hi and welcome, unfortunatly You ought to try do make somethink by Yourself and after some some attempts and fails ask question here... and also it cost money by the way to make good template as in Your example...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A suggestion is to read [Typesetting Exams in Latex](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Typesetting_exams_in_LaTeX) for a starting point, or [Latex/Teacher's Corner](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Teacher%27s_Corner)

Comment: I know it takes times and money to do so thanks all of you ! I appreciate your instructions and your help.  I have edited my question.   ;) :)